# Store file in sd card with name defined by user

Tags: android, filenames, sd-card

I'm trying to write code that saves the content of an edittext into a file in the sdcard. I found the following code that works:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    // write on SD card file data in the text box
    try {
        File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append(write_text.getText());
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}// onClick
}); // btnWriteSDFile
```

The problem is, this always saves the information to the same file, overwriting any previous saves.

How can I prompt the user to enter a different name for the file if the given file exists and save it under the name the user provides?

Note, I am rather new to this.

Comment: seriously, this is really a bad question I think. Can't you just think that you have to get the value from edittext and append to the file object creation constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a way..
In the onclick() popup an custom alert dialog with an edittext like [in this link](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/07/alert-box-code.html) and ask the user to enter the name and use this name as the file name in `File myFile = new File("/sdcard/"+myfilename+".txt");`

Answer (score 0):

First

Take the file name from a prompt dialog

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // write on SD card file data in the text box
    try {

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getApplicationContext());

    alert.setTitle("Title");
    alert.setMessage("Message");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this.getApplicationContext());
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      Editable value = input.getText();
      File myFile = new File("/sdcard/"+value .toString());
    myFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    myOutWriter.append(write_text.getText());
    myOutWriter.close();
    fOut.close();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
      }
    });

    alert.show();
```

}